# User forms to edit values in Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a spreadsheet and I am needing help with a setting up a userform to edit data within a specific worksheet. On my userform i have a combobox that has a list of users, I want to be able to select someone in this combox box, have it pull certain values from different columns into the sheet, and then allow me to update these values on the userform and have those saved back to the same cells the info was pulled from. I have been able to do the first part where it pulls the info through using the following code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("Daily Report").Range("AL" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LastRow
If Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(i, "D").Value = (Me.ComboBox2) Or _
Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(i, "D").Value = Val(Me.ComboBox2) Then
Me.TextBox1 = Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(i, "D").Value
Me.TextBox2 = Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(i, "AK").Value
Me.TextBox3 = Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(i, "B").Value
Me.TextBox4 = Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(i, "A").Value
Me.TextBox5 = Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(i, "C").Value
Me.ComboBox1 = Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(i, "AM").Value
Me.TextBox6 = Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(i, "AE").Value
Me.TextBox7 = Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(i, "AF").Value
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Would someone be able to help me with what i need to add / change to allow the values to be overtyped and then saved back to the sheet? I’ve tried searching for help online but havnt been able to find anything that I can understand enough to fit my needs. Also, is it possible to format  TextBox 6 and 7 so that they show the time  in the right format rather than convert it to text please? Thank you for any help you can offer

Comment: Can't you just do the reverse for each one? Like this: `Sheets("Daily Report").Cells(i, "AK").Value = Me.TextBox2`

Comment: So i've managed to work out how to write it back. i don't know why it works but it works. thank you for your help.